# Unable to get cookie in a Google Web application project

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I am trying to access web services through Java in a Google Web Application Project that i created.

The code is supposed to hit the endpoint URL and authenticate the user via the username/password and fetch the jsessionID that the server provides in a cookie. The authentication works fine but I am unable to extract the JsessionID from the cookie.

Following is the code I am using :-

```
private static String getCookieFromHeaders(HttpURLConnection wsConnection) {

    String headerName;
    String headerValue = "FAIL";
    for (int i = 0;; i++) {
        headerName = wsConnection.getHeaderFieldKey(i);
        if (headerName != null && headerName.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
            headerValue = wsConnection.getHeaderField(i);
            break;
        }
    }
    // return the header value (FAIL string for not found)
    return headerValue;
}
```

variable headerName is just giving "null" in an infinite loop.

Please advise, a complete Java noob here.

Comment: forgot to add ... this code is working absolutely fine when I create my eclipse project as a normal Java Project, but currently I need to run this in a servlet invoked from a JSP page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actually the cookie was being received, the header was "set-cookie" instead of "Set-Cookie".
Just couldn't spot it because of the stupid infinite loop!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use HttpServletRequest.getCookies()?

Comment: cookie is being fetched via HttpURLConnection, ie when I hit the web service end-point